# Is there a way to turn off the new IEnumerable Visualizer in VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to turn off the new IEnumerable Visualizer in VS 2022? I miss being able to get my object as a string so I can copy/paste and save it in a file. With the new IEnumerable Visualizer, I have to serialize the object as a string and put a breakpoint on it so that I can get the full object as a string.

Comment: This is good feedback to send to the product team using the VS Feedback tool.  They can let you know if there is such an option, and sending the feedback gives them a signal that there is a desire to turn it off (or that there is a discoverability issue if that already exists).

Comment: There is a feedback link for IEnumerableVisualizer on their DevBlog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/view-net-collections-with-the-new-ienumerable-debugger-visualizer/